# SAMBA AD new files group is "domain users" not the Primary Group

Tags: permissions, active-directory, samba4

We're using samba Acitve Directory (AD) Version `4.3.11-Ubuntu` with `Windows Active Directory Users and Computers` MMC console. The file server (attached to the domain) is `Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS`. In this case, the user is connecting via NFS.

When the user makes a directory (`mkdir ./testdir`) or creates a file (`touch testfile`) the directory and file both show up as owned by the group `domain users` instead of the group listed in `MS AD Users and Computers` as the primary group (in this case "students".)

**Is there a way to ensure new files/directories as created with the ownership of the Primary Group?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not with Samba 4.3.x, you will need to upgrade to 18.04, which will get you to at least 4.7.6 and you can then use (along with the winbindd 'ad' backend) this line in smb.conf:

idmap config SAMDOM:unix_primary_group = yes

Comment: OK. Good to know. That was in the works, so hopefully it will fix the issue. Thx.

Comment: When using idmap rid backend, there is also the same problem. Linux always reports the primary group as "Domain users", even if I change it on the DC